# How to lapply python function to r list using reticulate?

Tags: r, reticulate

Unexpected output when using Python function in R chunk with reticulate

Python Chunk:

```
def print_address(address):
    py_address = r.address
    print(py_address)
```

R Chunk:

```
address <- list("1 Main Street", "2 Hope Street")
lapply(address, py$print_address)
```

Actual:

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

Expected:

[[1]]
[1] "1 Main Street"

[[2]]
[1] "2 Hope Street"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this :

1)The python function is expected to print . But the output of  python console is not displayed . This looks like a typical flushing issue, which it is. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3271 
So the address will be printed if we flush the stdout in Python.

```
import sys
def print_address(address):
    py_address = address
    print(py_address)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

2) Our python function does not  return a value . I am not very sure how this works, but it seems in this case python returns a `null` to R. This does not seem to be a problem if we call the function directly, but in an `lapply` the returned null is added to list and implicitly gets printed. This will be printed even if you use `stdout.flush` in python.